# linking shared libraries with cmake on ubuntu

Tags: linux, cmake, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking

I am trying to link to shared object library (json-c) using cmake. I am a super beginner with cmake, and have tried the solutions in various SO posts to no avail.

I am following the directions laid out [here](https://github.com/json-c/json-c)

first step is to build the json-c library, which I did sucesfully.
Second step is linking to it. That's what I am having issues with. After following [these](https://github.com/json-c/json-c#linking-to-libjson-c-) instructions, my project directory structure looks like this:

Project Structure (before running make, build directory was empty)

```
base
|-json-c-master
  |-libjson-c.so
  |-libjson-c.a
  |-json.h
  :
  :
  :
  |-CMakeLists.txt
  |-Makefile
  |-libjson-c.so
|-build
  |-CMakeFiles
  |-
  :
  :
  |-Makefile.
|-src
   |-main.c
   |-project1.c
   |-project1.h
```

The contents of my CMakeLists.txt in ~/base/project1/CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(project1) set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)   
set(SOURCES src/main.c src/project1.h src/project1.c )   
add_executable(project1 ${SOURCES})  
find_package(json-c CONFIG)  
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE json-c::json-c)
```

then, I ran

```
cd build


cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/home/<username>/base/project1/json-c-master ..
```

this populated the previously empty build directory.

then, I ran `make`
and I got the error that in project1.h, which #includes "json.h", the file "json.h" was not found.

How can I link json.h to project1.h?
I again appreciate your patience, I am a super noob with cmake and I've been pouring over their documentation and other SO posts to no avail.

Comment: Please fix the formatting of this post.

Comment: The directory `json-c-master` looks like containing a **built tree** of the `json-c` project. You need to **install** that project (`make install`) for being able to use it with `find_package()`. And `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` should point to the installation tree, not to the build one.

Comment: when you say built tree and installation tree, what are you referrring to?

Comment: "build tree" denotes content of the build directory (from which you run `cmake`). "install tree" denotes content of the install directory, which is passed as `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` variable to cmake (this variable is noted in the documentation). The install directory is create during `make install`.